# Who are the influential personalities with regards to personal finance?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

### Who are the influential personalities with regards to personal finance?

Who do people listen to when it comes to personal finance?  Lets make a list of the personalities **both** big and small, and make a note about how likely they are to mention or help promote the site.

---

> Related:
>
> - [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)
> - [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)
> - [How do we promote our site?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-we-promote-our-site)

Comment: I'm not sure what the intent of this question is. Are you suggesting we identify them and try to find ways to promote the site through them?

Comment: @JohnFx I'm suggesting we identify them, and identify which ones we might want to promote through, and which there might be a real possibility of getting to.

Answer (score 6):

J.D.Roth of [Get Rich Slowly](http://www.getrichslowly.org/)

Answer (score 5):

[Joe Taxpayer](http://www.joetaxpayer.com), International Man of Mustache.  I actually think I've seen him around here a couple of times.

Comment: He's very eclectic; if you look closely, you might even find him on Mathematics.SE too. He even has a very respectable reputation, which is no minor achievement over there!

Answer (score 4):

[Suze Orman](http://www.suzeorman.com/) has made quite a name for herself in the world of personal finances.

Answer (score 3):

[Jim Cramer](http://www.cnbc.com/id/15838187/) of Mad Money.

I would actually be disappointed if he refused to mention the site.

Granted, he's more about investing than personal finance, but he's all about investing on your own.

Comment: good call he will be into it.

Answer (score 3):

I really like [Yves Smith](http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/author/yves-smith). She may not be as widely known as some of the names mentioned above but her writing is excellent and she is consistently responsive to her readers so you have a good chance of getting a mention.

A few more popular reader-responsive bloggers: [Mike Shedlock](http://globaleconomicanalysis.blogspot.com/), [Karl Denninger](http://market-ticker.org/akcs-www?archive-list=Market-Ticker), [Barry Ritholtz](http://www.ritholtz.com/blog/).

Lots of linkage... you should be able to take it from here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[Clark Howard](http://clarkhoward.com/), definitely.

Perhaps a few good non-spammy answers in the message forum with a signature line referencing this site might be a way to promote this site. Might want to check the T&C's of that site to make sure it isn't frowned on though.

Alternately, he has a call in show, if you could get through the screener you might be able to work a plug for the site in.

Answer (score 2):

The **[Bogleheads](http://www.bogleheads.org/)** website largely serves the same function as this site. There is a huge overlap in substance, so they might think of us as competitors. But the overlap isn't complete, and there is a stylistic difference.

The regulars there are certainly knowledgeable, and would be very good at answering questions here.

Answer (score 1):

From the UK, I'd say [Martin Lewis](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/) of Money Saving Expert.com

Comment: Great, we need more non-US personalities.

Answer (score 1):

The New York Times [Bucks Blog](http://bucks.blogs.nytimes.com/).

Comment: URL has changed, resource remains excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Dave Ramsey, personal finance.  Not so much about investing.

Comment: I like Dave, but I consider him highly unlikely to mention this site.  It's not his style.

Comment: @C. Ross.  Agreed he would probably not mention the site.  But we can dream :-)

Comment: I think we could get him to mention us but it would take some work to get us to the point where he would...

Answer (score 0):

[Steven Keen's Debtwatch](http://www.debtdeflation.com/blogs/)
It focuses more on explaining economics than personal finance, but the explanations are extremely useful to the layperson as he focuses on mortgages and property.
Also Australian

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can talk about investing without mentioning [Warren Buffett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Buffett). I don't know if he blogs or anything like that, but he's probably the most well-known investor in America, if not the world.