# Nearing Beta Completion Site scores still a worry [Edit: We are doing good Now]

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, meta

We are nearing out Beta Completion of 90 Days. However we are still some way off from making it to full site.
The scores as of 31st Oct 2010 are;
1,128 Questions: Okay
98% answered: Excellent
Avid Users:Okay
Answer Ratio: Excellent
423 Visit/Day: Worrying
More details at
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money

We have to increase the site visits. Else the site would become a ghost town.
Also if I see the top users (above 500+), there are quite a few users who are no longer logging in for past couple of months. We are loosing followers. We need to do something if we need to make this site a success.

Edit: I am Voting to close this question as its no longer relevant. We are doing good on all aspects for this site.

Comment: FYI We just passed 500 visits per day... We are now "Okay" in the metrics.    We've been creeping up over the last week or two.

Comment: For the record, we are now exceeding 2000 visits per day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not too worried about the last metric, Visits/day.  The most important metrics are the ones that we're scoring "Okay" or "Excellent" for.  Also, refer to:

- [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) (at [blog.stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com))

Anyway, Visits/day is mostly a function of how well the site is performing in Google searches.  When the site was known as **basicallymoney.com**, it was getting more traffic from Google.  [Refer to the comments you'll find here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-we-promote-our-site/120#120).  I think it will simply take more time for the new domain to re-establish, in Google's eyes, what reputation it had previously.  When we start ranking better in searches, the visits will go up.

The best thing each of us can do to help money.stackexchange.com rank better is to get quality inbound links to the site.  The [flair badge](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/flair) is one easy way users can help, for those people who are willing to post it and have a personal web site or blog.

Comment: good call promoting the flair badges is the way to go.

Comment: that was a good read, gave me a better understanding of what is a good question or answer and why.

Answer (score 3):

Any everybody should vote for answers that are good or at least reasonable.  Voting encourages new users to participate more and probably makes them feel less like outsiders.

You don't need to agree 100%, but if you can concede they have good points, vote.  Vote your favorite answer first.  Tack on a comment with some clarity if you don't back the answer fully.

Vote up good questions especially!  Vote early and vote often.